# Distribution of a binary string of a discrete time stochastic process

Tags: probability

Let $Z_t\in\{0,1\}^n$ be a discrete time stochastic process such that $Z_0=[0,0,\cdots,0]$. At time $t+1$, we go from $Z_t$ to $Z_{t+1}$ as follows: Let the leftmost bit of $Z_t$ be $L_t$. Add $W_{t+1}$ to $L_t$ where $W_{t+1}\in\{0,1\}$ w.p. $1/2$ each and $W_t's$ are independent. Then, append $L_t+W_{t+1}+$ sum of the remaining $n-1$ bits of $Z_t$ modulo $2$ to the right side of $Z_t$ and delete the leftmost bit of $Z_t$ to get $Z_{t+1}$. For example:

Let $Z_t=[0,1,1,1]$ and say we choose $0$ for the left most bit (happens w.p. $1/2$), so if we now append $0+1+1+1 \mod 2$ to $Z_t$ and delete the leftmost bit of $Z_t$, we get $Z_{t+1}=[1,1,1,1]$.

> Let $A_t$ be the set of appended bits by time $t$. I am checking if $A_t$ is uniform over $\{0,1\}^t$ for $1\leq t< n$?

My attempt: I think the answer is yes by induction. Let $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots,Y_t$ be the appended bits by time $t$. Clearly, $Y_1\in\{0,1\}$ w.p. $1/2$ each, so $Y_1$ is uniform over $A_1$. By induction hypothesis, let $\{Y_1,Y_2,\cdots,Y_t\}$ be uniform over $\{0,1\}^t$. At time $t+1$, the appended bit is $L_t+W_{t+1}+Y_1+Y_2+\cdots Y_t=Y_{t+1}$ and if we condition $Y_{t+1}$ on $\{Y_1,Y_2,\cdots, Y_t\}$, I think $Y_{t+1}\in \{0,1\}$ w.p. $1/2$ each because $L_t\perp W_{t+1}$ and $L_t+W_{t+1}\in \{0,1\}$ w.p. $1/2$ each. So $\{Y_1,\cdots,Y_t,Y_{t+1}\}$ is uniform over $\{0,1\}^{t+1}$ by induction hypothesis. Is this correct?

Comment: "Add $W_{t+1}$ to $L_t$ where $W_{t+1}\in\{0,1\}$ w.p. $1/2$ each and $W_t's$ are independent" after this what do you with the sum?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan $L_t+W_{t+1}+$ sum of other remaining $n-1$ bits modulo $2$ is appended to $Z_t$ as given in the example.

Comment: ok you may want to change "Then, append sum of the bits of $Z_t$ modulo $2$ on the right side of $Z_t$" to "Then, append $L_t + W_{t+1}+$sum of the remaining $n-1$ bits of $Z_t$ modulo $2$ on the right side of $Z_t$

Comment: The appended bit is $W_{t+1}+(Y_t+Y_{t-1}+\cdots+ Y_{t-n}) mod 2=Y_{t+1}$. Rest of the argument looks good to me. But maybe a simpler argument is that - the sum of the n digits at time = t is 0 or 1(w.p $\frac{1}{2}$), Then even after adding $W_{t+1}$ it is uniform.